# Stepwise Logistic Regression, stopping at best N features

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet

I'm interested in exploring what shakes out of a stepwise logistic regression from the top **N** variables...whether that is 5 or 15 depending upon my preference of this.

I've tried to play around with the caret package:

```
set.seed(23)
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
traincontrol <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, returnResamp = "all", savePredictions='all', classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

glmstep_mod <- train(Class ~.,
                     data = Sonar,
                     method = "glmStepAIC", 
                     trControl = traincontrol,
                     metric = "ROC", 
                     trace = FALSE)
```

But this spits back a bunch of different variables for the final model.

Any packages out there that let's me do this, code I can generate myself, or missing parameters to these functions for this?  So I could say max_variables = N?  And give it multiple tries to see the trade-off?

I normally experiment with lasso or some other model types and I'm aware of the advantages/disadvantages that stepwise provides.

Comment: how about using neural net?  library(nnet);  nnet_mod <- train(Class ~.,
                     data = Sonar,
                     method = "nnet", 
                     trControl = traincontrol,
                     metric = "ROC", 
                     trace = FALSE);
nnet_imp<-varImp(nnet_mod);
plot(nnet_imp)

Comment: Appreciate it but only care about logistic right now.

Comment: you should take a look at [`bestglm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bestglm/index.html) and [glmulti](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmulti/index.html). Here is a decent [tutorial](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2897_9220b21cfc0c43a396ff9abf122bb351.html)

Comment: ty @missuse, wasn't aware of these I will inspect.